# Adjust matrix Array

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

Hello  I have a display 320X420 and I have two array one represent 
rows its size is 16 and the other represent columns its size is 21 and I'm using a font size let consider 20 or whatever number
I have to assign a specific offset at each entry in the array(both for rows and cols), that entry correspond one value in the matrix offset, could somebody give an advice on how to fill those array?

I have tried simply fill it with `for` and adding **font size** but I think there are other way to do it more preciscely.

this question seem to be more about algorithm I did not find a forum an Im using a Algorithm , math, matrix tags. a c++ example is ok but
the programming language is not a problem.

```
const int WIDTH  =320;
const int HEIGHT =480;
const int character_size = 20;

int rows[MAX_ROWS + 1];
int cols[MAX_COLS + 1];


int q_element_w = WIDTH / character_size;
int q_element_h = HEIGHT / character_size;

///maybe a for loop for fill with specific value rows and col


...
```

my question arise here how to set specific value for rows and cols using as a limit q_element*

thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate question for StackOverflow. Allow me to suggest that you find a site with "forum" in the name. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you have so far.  That way people will be able to help you better.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question. What entries do you want in `rows` and `cols`? Is it simply the cumulated character size (i.e. `0, 20, 40, 60`...)?

Comment: What Im looking for is way to create a matrix of coordinate for a fixed size with a specific size for each row-col combination, but instead of having a two or three dimensional array using separate identifier(I know variables are just variables).